# php db programming

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

how to insert multiple values in single row of database using php?
For example the table contains name,email,address line1,address line2,note.
The Database table contains name,email,address,note.
i.e  for a single user address line 1,address line 2 should come under address .Please help me find out

Answer (score 2):

You can concate address one and address two like this

```
$address=$addressline1.$addressline2;
$q="insert into table (name,email,address,note) values($name,$email,$address,$note)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You appned your address line1, and address line2 together using string concatenation; though i m not sure if that's the best way you want.

[1] http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html